# Alternative To Page Refresh PHP

Tags: php, html, refresh, clock, live-update

I'm working on learning PHP and I wanted to make a clock with some crypto-like number images I made.

The problem I'm running in to is that I want the clock to be updated every second but without refreshing the page. So my question is, how would you suggest I go about doing this?

Right now I use the HTML page refresh which causes my images to flicker every reload.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Code below:

```
<!--
    * By megabyteGhost
    * megabyteGhost.tumblr.com
-->


<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0.5" >
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="black">
    <?php
        date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
        $hour = date(H); 
        $minutes = date(i);
        $seconds = date(s);

        echo '<img src="images/'.$hour.'.png">';
        echo '<img src="images/'.$minutes.'.png">';
        echo '<img src="images/'.$seconds.'.png">';
    ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: that's basically what java script was made for....

Comment: Not possible with only php. You'll need javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (only) use Javascript:

(i added alt tag, because the images obiously can't be loaded here)

```js
setInterval(function(){
  var date = new Date();
  
  var hr = date.getHours();
  var min = date.getMinutes();
  var sec = date.getSeconds();
  
  //document.getElementById("hours").src = "images/" + hr + ".png";
  document.getElementById("hours").alt = hr;
  //document.getElementById("minutes").src = "images/" + min + ".png";
  document.getElementById("minutes").alt = min;
  //document.getElementById("seconds").src = "images/" + sec + ".png";
  document.getElementById("seconds").alt = sec;
},1000)
```

```html
<span id="timer">
  <img src="" id="hours" alt="0">:
  <img src="" id="minutes" alt="0">:
  <img src="" id="seconds" alt="0">
</span>
```

be aware that you should preload the images!

**JS:**

```
//before starting the interval:
var preloadedImages = [];
for(var i=0;i<60;i++){
    preloadedImages[i] = new Image();
    preloadedImages[i].src = "images/"+i+".png";
}
```

whis way, the browser keeps them in memory, so you won't have a flickering second counter when the images are loaded for the first time

**[EDIT]:**
By the way....avoid this:

```
$hour = date(H); 
$minutes = date(i);
$seconds = date(s);
```

should be this:

```
$hour = date("H"); 
$minutes = date("i");
$seconds = date("s");
```

else they will be checked as constant variables and print out a notice, which will spam your logs, if you have the log level low enough...also, it needs more processing time (no big deal with only three calls, but is accumulative if used more often...)

Comment: Thanks for your lesson and the PHP advice (you would think I'd know to put in quotes, guess I forgot...not new to programming just to PHP so that's an amateur mistake).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean. It was an amateur mistake because I couldn't have made that mistake in any other language.

Answer (score 1):

This  can be  done  with Javscript , Ajax or Jquery whichever you have  experience  with .Only php is not  sufficient  enough  to  do  this as  without  refreshing  you can't request  something from the  server  without  ajax.

Answer (score 1):

The sad news is that php cannot do it. This happens because php was made do be a pre-processed script. That means that when you access a php page, the server will read that code, execute all the lines internally and, if there is any output, it will be sent to your browser. You HTML code is actually an output of your php script. Is VERY important to understand this when learning php.

The output can be an HTML text, JavaScript, only text or even images. What is important to have in your mind is that any output will only be shown at your browser after the server is done with reading your code. So any dynamic action can't be done using php. When you need dynamic, you need JavaScript.